# Ctrl-Shift-F not searching all sources in chrome's developer console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should search all sources. However, for me, it's not picking up some code that I can see is there when I browse the 'elements' tab.

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be, and how I can get a search to include truly all sources?

Answer (score 7):

You need to turn on 'Search in content scripts' in Chrome Settings in this case.

[image: Search in content scripts]

Comment: I've checked that box and it still isn't returning the result. I've tried restarting the browser but with no luck.

Comment: @ANON That's strange. I don't appear to have this issue myself. I don't know if it could be some caching issue. You could try create a new Chrome person profile, make sure setting is ON and try again?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I'm having same issue.

Comment: @ThePoet Nope, never solved it. Let me know if you find anything. I'll let you know if I find anything but that's not likely as I've stopped using this feature.

Comment: This answer is still the solution for the current Chrome version. I think it is annoying that this checkbox is not checked by default (mine becomes not checked occasionally). I cannot see why there is a need for such an option in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`F` wasn't working anymore.
You can follow these steps if you are facing same issue.

1. Press f12 to open developer tools
2. Click on vertical ellipsis on the right side of developer toolbar to
   open it's options.
3. Click "More Tools"
4. Click on "Serach"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "ALT + D"
It's working in Google Chrome as well as in Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case search was actually working just the bottom bar was shrunk/minimized that i was not able to see it. check that...